# Python: пробел заменяется знаком "-"

Tags: python

Господа и дамы: прохожу курс обучения python, код проходит проверку тремя пачками данных. Суть проблемы такова: в одной из пачек данных появляются отрицательные значения, и при выводе "-" съедает необходимый по требованиям пробел:

Потрачено ккал: 336.000.
Потрачено ккал:-81.320.
Потрачено ккал: 157.500.

соответственно, хочу узнать существует ли способ избежать такого сценария?
PS добавить пробел - не выход, тест не пройдут другие две пачки данных.

```
print(f'Тип тренировки:{self.training_type};',
      f'Длительность:{self.duration: .3f} ч.;',
      f'Дистанция:{self.distance: .3f} км;',
      f'Ср. скорость:{self.speed: .3f} км/ч;',
      f'Потрачено ккал:{self.calories: .3f}.')
```

Comment: Если коротко, то пробел внутри фигурных скобок перед `.3f` игнорируется. Если нужен пробел перед выводимым числом, вынесите его слева от фигурных скобок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В форматировании есть флаги для чисел:

- `+`: знак ставится для всех чисел - `'+25'`,`'-25'`
- `-`: для отрицательных '-', ничего для положительных - `'25'`,`'-25'`
- (Пробел): для отрицательных '-', пробел для положительных - `' 25'`,`'-25'`

Итого ваш код примерно такой:

```
print(f'Тип тренировки:{self.training_type};',
      f'Длительность: {self.duration:-.3f} ч.;',
      f'Дистанция: {self.distance:-.3f} км;',
      f'Ср. скорость: {self.speed:-.3f} км/ч;',
      f'Потрачено ккал: {self.calories:-.3f}.')
```

Comment: Именно то, что мне было нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать так

```
print(f'Число: {-81.32:.3f};')
print(f'Число: {157.5:.3f};')
```